# Questioned about why I was leaving

Tags: resignation

I have handed in my two week notice, upon doing these, my current employer wanted to know right away what they were offering me.  I tried every way to get around this question without answering, but they just kept asking. So I threw out a number I knew they could never match, which isn't the real offer.  Then I was asked where my new job would be again I tried to get around this question with no avail, so I provided them with the answer.  Now, I am concerned that they will contact my new employer and tell them what I said as this is a small town and everyone knows everyone.  As my new employer is the husband of a friend, he was concerned with how handing in my noticed went, so I was upfront and truthful about what I had done,  I am also concern now that they may recant their offer or think less of me for a lie, that was just meant to get my current employer off my back. Any advice would be apprieciated.

Comment: Did you try answering with "No!"

Comment: I tried no, I even tried to change the topic. This was my first time having to hand in my notice.

Comment: Did they threaten to send goons to thrash you if you didn't answer? Or did you have reason to believe they would? If not, then the only "correct" answer to this is procrastination. That is, when someone asked you about your new job, you neither tell them "Oh sure, I will tell you" nor "Go to hell, I am not telling you". Instead you just say, "Sure, I will let you know soon". Keep doing this for two weeks and you are good.

Comment: They asked about your current salary, probably, because they were trying to establish if your departure was "about money". All you had to do is say that you're not leaving because of the salary and that you are just making a career decision.

Comment: Just give any answer, what does it matter? "They're giving me a slide from my cubicle to the refectory."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be straightforward. Tell your new employer what happened: you were put under pressure. You resisted initially, but they put you under so much pressure that the only thing you could think of to get them off your back was by quoting a salary figure out of la-la land. Tell him you're none too proud of the way you got them off your back, but it worked. And tell him that's all there is to the story.

Don't volunteer anything. Tell your story only if your new employer asks.

The decision to rescind the offer is, of course, your new employer's. Hopefully, he understands that you did this only under duress. Personally, I would still hire you unless the job requires that you handle yourself well under pressure. However, I would find it hard to do better than you did, given that your current employer controls all physical entry points and exits out of his business :)

I have occasionally said to some of those who put me under pressure and pressed me hard "Ask me no questions, and I will tell you no lies".

Answer (score 3):

For the future my answer to your current bosses questions would simply be:

"I am sorry but I am unwilling to disclose that information at this time.  Once I have completed my probationary period with the new company I will be more than happy to discuss my experience with you over coffee if you like."

Be nice and respectful but decline to answer.  If pushed just keep repeating "I am sorry but I am unwilling to disclose that information at this time."  Realize that they can not make any threats that have any substance so long as you keep your information to yourself.  That means not telling any of your coworkers either.  These can be sidestepped with "You know I would love to tell you but then you could be in a tough position if Lundberg starts pressuring you as well.  Best for everyone if I just keep it quiet."

Since you have already told them, I would hope for the best.  If your current company calls over there and tries to mess with your position they will look bad.  If they are successful then you should consult a lawyer because you may have a cause for action against them.

If the company does question you about it, first apologize for problems your boss is creating for them, and then deny.  "I have never disclosed the salary that we agreed to anyone (outside of my immediate family if needed).  Mr Lundberg may have misunderstood something.  I am comfortable with the amount we agreed to and am looking forward to starting work with you."

That should be enough to get you through any turbulence with the new company.  Do not try to paint it as you were trying to hide your new position, and definitely do not admit to claiming the higher amount, but also do not call your boss a liar or attempt to portray him in a bad light.  He is doing that on his own let him hang himself no need to get your hands dirty with that.